# Don't Save csv first line as header

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I'm using the following code to load my CSV file into a DataTable object. The problem is that the first line from the CSV file is loaded into the DataTable as the header row and not as a data row. How can I make all lines from the CSV file load as data rows and make datatable header row empty or any thing.
 This is my code

```
private DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csvfilename))
        {
            string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add(header);
            }
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = rows[i];
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying the first row in the DataTable is the CSV headers?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: No, I don't have headers in csv file so i don't need headers in datatable or make it empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use the first ReadLine statement to add the Header objects. You only use the second ReadLine to populate rows in the DataTable. Try this:

```
private DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable()
{
    bool firstRow = true;
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csvfilename))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] values = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');

            if (firstRow)
            {
                firstRow = false;
                for (int i = 0;i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    dataTable.Columns.Add("Column" + i);
                }
            }

            DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = values[i];
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: This should work as long as every line in the CSV file has the same number of values in it

Answer (score -2):

EDITED:
Sorry about that I forgot to add the column headers... This should "workish". Unfortunately I dont have a C# debugger in front of me to get the syntax exact, but I believe you can figure out what I am trying to do.

You are explicitly reading the "Header". If I am understanding you correctly you simply need to remove the header management. This will leave you with columns with no header though or a null header.

```
private DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csvfilename))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = rows[i];
            }
            //IF the dataTable column count is less than the row column count add some columns.
            if (dataTable.Columns.size() < dr.Columns.size()){
                for(int i = 0; i < dr.Columns.size(); i++){
                   dataTable.Columns.add("");
                }
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: You're answer will not work as there will be no columns in the DataTable, and you reference a "headers" variable, which does not exist..?

Comment: Sorry about that man, I was just working on some Java stuff and forgot that C# requires the columns to be manually defined. Good luck!

Comment: You should delete the answer